# efficiency graph size calculation with power function

Tags: python, time-complexity, runtime-error, simplify, pow

I am looking to improve the following simple function (written in python), calculating the maximum size of a specific graph:

```
def max_size_BDD(n):
i = 1
size = 2
while i <= n:
    size += min(pow(2, i-1), pow(2, pow(2, n-i+1))-pow(2, pow(2, n-i)))
    i+=1
    print(str(i)+" // "+ str(size))
return size
```

if i give it as input n = 45, the process gets killed (probably because it takes too long, i dont think it is a memory thing, right?). How can i redesign the following algorithm such that it can handle larger inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My proposal: While the original function starts to run into troubles at ~10, I have practically no limitations (even for n = 100000000, I stay below 1s).

```
def exp_base_2(n):
    return 1 << n


def max_size_bdd(n):
    # find i at which the min branch switches
    start_i = n
    while exp_base_2(n - start_i + 1) < start_i:
        start_i -= 1

    # evaluate all to that point
    size = 1 + 2 ** start_i

    # evaluate remaining terms (in an uncritical range of n - i)
    for i in range(start_i + 1, n + 1):
        val = exp_base_2(exp_base_2(n - i))
        size += val * (val - 1)
        print(f"{i} // {size}")
    return size
```

Remarks:

- Core idea: avoid the large powers of 2, as they are not necessary to calculate if you use the `min` in the end.
- I did all this in a rush, maybe I can add more explanation later... if anyone is interested. Then, I could also do a more decent verification of the new implementation.
- The effect of `exp_base_2` should be negligible after doing all the math to optimize the original calculations. I did this optimization before I went into analysis.
- Maybe a complete closed-form solution is possible. I did not invest the time for further investigations.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot! i dont think there is a closed form solution otherwise they would have included it in the paper from which i got this formula : https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01880774/file/newton.17.bdd.intuition.pdf

The core idea is more then clear from the code itself, but it is surprising to me that it makes such a big difference.

Comment: Otherwise you have to compute insane 2 ** n values.